# Can infinite limit on products of N terms ignore $\mathcal{O}(N^{-2})$ in each term?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, power-series, infinite-product

Is the following true in general?
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\prod_{n=1}^N\left(a_n+b_n\left(\frac 1 N\right) + \mathcal{O}\left(\left(\frac 1 N\right)^2\right)\right) = \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\prod_{n=1}^N\left(a_n+b_n\left(\frac 1 N\right) \right)$$

If not, what are some exceptions? Are there any conditions that make the above always satisfied?
ETA:
**One example of the above:**
$$e^{\frac 1 {2N}}=1+\frac 1 {2N}+\frac 1 {N^2}\frac 1 8+\frac 1 {N^3}\frac 1 {48} + \cdots $$

and

$$N\ln\left(\frac 1 {1-\frac 1 N}\right)=1+\frac 1 {2N}+\frac 1 {N^2}\frac 1 3+\frac 1 {N^3}\frac 1 4 + \cdots $$

Calculating, $\prod^N_{n=1} e^{\frac 1 {2N}} =\sqrt{e}$, it is also possible to find $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\prod^N_{n=1} N\ln\left(\frac 1 {1-\frac 1 N}\right)= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(N\ln\left(\frac 1 {1-\frac 1 N}\right)\right)^N =\sqrt{e}$$

Solving it is very lengthy, but wolfram alpha can generate all the [steps](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit%20n%20to%20infinity%20of%20%28-nln%281-1%2Fn%29%29%5En). They give the same result despite only matching on the first two terms.
The compound interest definition of euler number is also an example, specifically taking $e^{\frac 1 N}$ and letting the $\mathcal{O}(N^{-2})$ function be ignored.

Comment: I am trying to show that it is the case but am stuck and unable to find discussion online as well. I haven't been able to find exceptions either. For example, I tried the limit of N product of $e^{1/2N}$ and $N\ln\left(\frac 1 {1 - \frac 1 N}\right)$ which have same power series only upto $N^{-1}$ and they both seem to converge to $\sqrt e$ on desmos.

Comment: What is $ T $ ?

Comment: Some constant from the origin of this question. sorry, I'll remove it since it distracts from the question.

Comment: If $a_n=b_n=0$, then no.

Comment: I think if $a_n=b_n=0$, the LHS is of the order $N^{-2N}$ which does go to zero.

Comment: Seems like for $1+O(N^{-2})$ function independent on variable $n$, taking log on both sides and evaluating limits, it will always result in 1. So I need a clear contradiction.

Comment: It's definitely true (and very easy to prove) given $a_n = 1$ and $b_n = b$ are constant, as in your example. (If $a_n = a \ge 0$ is constant, we more generally get a limit of $0$ if $a_n < 1$, $e^b$ if $a_n = 1$, and $\infty$ if $a_n > 1$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both $\prod_{n=1}^N (a_n + b_n N^{-1} + \mathcal O(N^{-2}))$ and $\prod_{n=1}^N (a_n + b_n N^{-1})$ converge (and thus make sense... see the comments) then:$$\frac{\prod_{n=1}^N (a_n + b_n N^{-1} + \mathcal O(N^{-2}))}{\prod_{n=1}^N (a_n + b_n N^{-1})} = \prod_{n=1}^N\frac{ a_n + b_n N^{-1} + \mathcal O(N^{-2})}{a_n + b_n N^{-1}} = \prod_{n=1}^N(1 + \mathcal O(N^{-2}))$$
If this $\mathcal O$ notation doesn't depend on $n$ then we are done, since this is simply $(1+\mathcal O(N^{-2}))^N \longrightarrow 1$ (as $N \to \infty$).

If there is dependence on $n$ then things become trickier. As a simple example, consider:
$$\prod_{n=1}^N (1 + N^{-1} + n N^{-2})= \frac{\Gamma(1+2N+N^2)}{N^{2N}\Gamma(1+N+N^2)} \longrightarrow e^{3/2}$$
$$\prod_{n=1}^N (1 + N^{-1})= (1+N^{-1})^N \longrightarrow e$$

So the $n$-dependence does really matter.